# Why is the address of string const in C language so smaller and always staying in the same address

Tags: c, string

I am learning C and I have a question about the const string in C language.

I run the following program(source code) twice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str = "ABCD";
    printf("str content: %s, pointer address of str: %p\n", str, &str);
    printf("str[0]: %c address: %p\n", str[0], &str[0]);
    printf("str[1]: %c address: %p\n", str[1], &str[1]);
    printf("str[2]: %c address: %p\n", str[2], &str[2]);
    printf("str[3]: %c address: %p\n", str[3], &str[3]);

    printf("%p\n", &"hello");
    return 0;
}
```

An its twice output is:

```
#
[ekeyme@castor tmp]$ ./t
str content: ABCD, pointer address of str: 0x7fffa33d8508
str[0]: A address: 0x400668
str[1]: B address: 0x400669
str[2]: C address: 0x40066a
str[3]: D address: 0x40066b
0x4006f2

#
[ekeyme@castor tmp]$ ./t
str content: ABCD, pointer address of str: 0x7fff055d8c38
str[0]: A address: 0x400668
str[1]: B address: 0x400669
str[2]: C address: 0x40066a
str[3]: D address: 0x40066b
0x4006f2
```

My question is why address of A/B/C/D in the string (char *)"ABCD" is so small, e.g. `0x400668`, it doesn't like the address, `0x7fffa33d8***`, of the variables `&str`. And why the address of A/B/C/D is consistent in twice output, e.g. for `A` its address is always `0x400668`.

Comment: It's depending on the host environment

Comment: not in the same segment. There's a highly voted duplicate from last week talking about that.

Comment: In (modern) operating systems memory is all in virtual address spaces. Each program execution has it's own distinct address space and is separated from physical memory locations. This doesn't "guarantee" the observed output/stability, but rather explains how it can be.

Comment: It is not a duplicate; in this case the code is just incorrect.  It attempts to print the address of the and then the address its members, but the first address print is erroneous.  It has nothing to do with virtual addresses or text/data segments.

Comment: The good question would be why is the address of `str` always different? Does anybody know?

Comment: @Marian : Print the address af `main` too; that may help.  It is relative to the location of the code.  It is the OS that locates the code at runtime, not the language.

Comment: I vote duplicate. Because I use `objdump -s -j .rodata /mnt/bioinfo/ekeyme/tmp/t`(from that duplicated question) to inspect the read only data section(see result: https://gist.github.com/ekeyme/7e3513caddb072d7f33e0e31e3505b71). I could see my `ABCD` is start at `0x400668`.

Answer (score 1):

The addresses you are seeing are the [virtual / logical addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). These are *not* actual physical addresses in memory. These addresses are converted to some actual address using a [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table). It's fine if the CPU generates the same logical address every time, as the page table might map these logical addresses to different physical addresses.

Comment: Look at the code again. It is incorrect. The result has nothing to do with stack vs text segments.

Comment: @Clifford The code is not incorrect. Just that the printed string is not in agreement with what the OP (most probably) means. Besides, the addresses printed are always logical. Only the OS gets to know the actual physical addresses.

Comment: The code is indeed valid, but perhaps not what the OP intended; ie.semantically incorrect.  But indeed my assumption may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your `str` is a local variable. It is placed in the system stack which is on your system placed on the top of the address space. On the other side, the string itself is placed on the lowest adresses together with the compiled 
code of your program

Comment: So why the address of a char in the string const is always consistent? It seems that these adress are distance(offset) from something like the start address of `string const` when compiled.

Comment: @EkeymeMo Because the software that loads your executable into memory is a deterministic program. That does not need to be the case (google "address space layout randomization"), but it appears to be that way on your system. Anyway, this is nothing that you can/should rely on, it's heavily dependent on the compiler/linker/loader.

Comment: You can imagine it as if the executable file `t` was simply stored in the memory from some address (let's say zero) up. Because constant strings are in the executable file and you load the same file each time, strings are always placed to the same place in the memory.

Comment: Look at the code again.  It is incorrect.  The result has nothing to do with stack vs text segments.

Comment: @Clifford The result corresponds to the code. OP asked to explain the output not to correct its code.

Comment: @Marian : You have a point.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is simply incorrect; in the first case you are printing `&str` rather than `str`

```
printf("str content: %s, str address: %p\n", str, str);
```